# reading a text file in python and printing occurrence of a phrase

Tags: python, string, text-files

I'm struggling to get my code to work. I've been supplied with some variables to work with: The variable **P** is my file path, designated as content/textfiles/empty.txt; while the variable **S** is my string, designated as parrot. The end goal is to find out how many times Parrot (S) appears in my text file (P). The following is the variables and information I have been supplied with, and immediately following is my crude code that is attempting to complete my task:

```
    import sys
    P= sys.argv[1]
    S= sys.argv[2]

    file = open(P,'r')
    data = file.read()

    count = 0
    if S in P:
        count += 1
    print(count)
    file.close()
```

The primary issue is that I am supposed to have a return of 3 for output, but my code is only counting 1 occurrence, but I have no idea why.

Comment: You aren't actually counting the number of occurrences anywhere. You only ever increment count once.

Comment: Check the [count method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) of strings, such as your `data` variable.

Comment: Thanks Rory! That did the trick!  It took me a bit to understand, but after editing my code, I got it to work! I'm editing my post with the solution!

Comment: Remember, don't post the answer in the question, post it as a new answer

Answer (score 0):

[Answer previously posted on question]:

```
file = open(P,'r')
data = file.read()
count = data.count(S)
print(count)
```